# How can I include a new command in \input

Tags: input, debugging

I'm trying to variate the file name by creating a newcommand `\lbname` in LaTeX. by printing out `\lbname`, I got `lo3.txt` in this case, but it wouldn't work in `\input` command. I get an error "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000".

```
\newcommand{\experr}{\input{examp_error..txt}}
\newcommand{\lbname}{lo\experr\unskip .txt}
\newcommand{\lb}{\input{\lbname}}
```

Comment: the posted code does not generate any error, you may get an error depending what is in `examp_error..txt` and how and where you use the command `\lb` (which seems to be the same as `\lbname`, it is not clear what is the intention of the last definition). But you have given no indication of that use, so it is impossible to say why you get an error.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong code. I was trying to include \lbname in \input

Comment: Calling `\lb` would do `\input{lo\input{examp_error..txt}\unskip .txt}` which I can't see the usefulness of. What's in `examp_error..txt`?

Comment: It's a text file from SAS code. In this case it's "3", but it varies.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the snippet in the question:

- `\input{}` is not expandable, because it also checks, if the file exists.
  The primitive `\@@input` could be used instead, but there are better ways, see below.
- `\unskip` is also not expandable and can therefore not be used as part of a file  name. See package `trimspaces` to remove spaces at the end of a macro.

Both issues can be avoided by using package `catchfile`. Assuming the file `examp_err.txt` (the two dots in the questions are a typo?) contains the number `3`, then

```
\CatchFileEdef\experr{examp_error.txt}{\endlinechar=-1 }
```

will define the macro `\experr`, which expands to `3`. `\endlinechar=-1` removes the line ends, which would be converted to a space otherwise. Therefore `\unskip` or package `trimspaces` are not needed.

Then, `\experr` can be safely used as part of a file name:

```
\newcommand*{\lbname}{lo\experr.txt}
```

or

```
\edef\lbname{lo\experr.txt}
```

The file name `\lbname` can then be used in `\input` or whatever you want to do with it.

Full code snippet:

```
\usepackage{catchfile}

\CatchFileEdef\experr{examp_error.txt}{\endlinechar=-1 }
\edef\lbname{lo\experr.txt}
```

If `examp_error.txt` contains `3`, then `\lbname` expands to `lo3.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution from TeX primitive level:

```
\newread\exfile
\openin\exfile=examp_error.txt % the file where "3" or similar is included"
\ifeof\exfile \def\experr{} \errmessage{the file examp_error.txt doesn't exist}
\else {\endlinechar=-1 \global\read\exfile to\experr}\fi
\input lo\experr.txt % does \input lo3.txt or something similar
```

This works in classical TeX and in LaTeX too. Note, that `\input` is TeX primitive in non-LaTeX formats. So, we use it as a primitive without `{braces}` in its argument.